# While tyring to open front camera throws errors

Tags: android, android-camera, adt, eclipse-adt

I am trying to open the front camera of an android device using following code which I borrowed from stackoverflow:

```
private android.hardware.Camera openFrontFacingCameraGingerbread() {
        int cameraCount = 0;
        Camera cam = null;
        android.hardware.Camera.CameraInfo cameraInfo = new Camera.CameraInfo();
        cameraCount = Camera.getNumberOfCameras();
        for ( int camIdx = 0; camIdx < cameraCount; camIdx++ ) {
            Camera.getCameraInfo( camIdx, cameraInfo );
            if ( cameraInfo.facing == Camera.CameraInfo.CAMERA_FACING_FRONT  ) {
                try {
                    cam = Camera.open( camIdx );
                } catch (RuntimeException e) {

                }

                cam.release();
            }
        }
```

This looks good I do not see any errors. I am calling this method from my MainActivity as soon as it loads.

I do some "!" signs on my project icon in the project explorer but then I decided that let me go ahead and run. Let's see what happens. Now that I run it, I see following erros:

[image: Eclipse ADT errors]

It says method called after release? release is the last thing that I am calling...

Comment: To include stack traces in your SO questions, shift-select the lines in LogCat, then press `Ctrl-C` to copy those lines to the clipboard.

Comment: I think the camera isn't opened yet. First, check if the camera is opened. Before you use the camera you have to add the permission in AndroidManifest.xml. ` <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />`

Comment: Actually, this error is resolved. It turned out that I was not releasing the camera in the function an dit did not like it.